# Chaining transistors: why does first LED not light?

Tags: transistors

I am trying to understand transistors by experimenting. Having a pushbutton drive a single transistor to switch on an LED works, but trying to drive the second transistor from the first has me confused.

Even though the second transistor turns on and drives its own LED, the LED of the first transistor doesn't switch "on" any more.

Can someone explain the theory behind the first LED not turning on?

This question is similar to my [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/466482/how-do-i-chain-transistors-so-that-the-first-transistor-switches-on-the-seco) but I specifically want to know *why* this circuit behaves this way.

[image: my circuit]

Comment: Theoretically the Left Led should glow from basic circuit concept point of view, the problem is the series 220 resistor from battery. It will decrease the voltage at upper side of 264 resistor to level the Left Led has too little current. Btw, it is not a good aproach drive Led thru base of (right) transistor.

Comment: Both LEDs should go on when the switch is pressed. If it fails to behave that way maybe the circuit is not as you have presented.  It's a strange circuit, I don't know why you would do that.

Comment: A more conventional solution would be to use a PNP transistor for the second LED and add it's base as a load to the first unless you want to use the first LED as an indicator of the base current.

Comment: Andy, what kind of LEDs are you using? I'm just curious.

Comment: the battery is installed backward

Comment: @jsotola Well, the diagram looks funny. But if the battery were backwards I think both LEDs would be off.

Comment: Andy, would you be able to accept clear proof that both LEDs must have some current in them if your schematic is accurate and the parts you are using are not broken? But it's possible, for example, that one of your LEDs -- the one you claim is OFF -- is actually just a damaged LED from too high of a current it in, earlier. Such an LED will light up, by itself, but might not in this case in the position of LED 1. If so, then if you replace it with a different one you will see it light up slightly in this circuit. (Or swap the two LEDs.)

Comment: Some updates: when initially applying current the second led flashes on very briefly (¼ second)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ak51ZHjDJj8

Comment: 1/4 second? Way too low resistor value installed from heating the LED to oblivion? Battery depleated?

Comment: You don't say what it is you are trying to achieve.  Do you want both LEDs on and off at the same time, or do you want them to alternate when you press the switch (one turns off and one turns on)?

Comment: just trying to understand the why of things. I expect both LED's to turn on

Comment: when building up the circuit, I measure 32mA between D1 and Q1' s collector, but only when nothing is connected to Q2's collector. As soon as I add the led with or without resistor to Q2's collector the amperage between D1 and Q1's collector drops to zero.

Answer (score 1):

The Circuit-Lab Simulator says that both LEDs should turn on, although D2 will be brighter than D1 as there's almost 3 times the current flowing though it.
Check your construction and take some measurements to debug what's going wrong.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuypx9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: R4 is 220 ohms in the OPs diagram.

Comment: @Mattman944 - fixed, although it made little difference to the outcome.